# Unmet dependencies (libgssapi-krb5-2: Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.10.1 + dfsg-4) but 1:10 + dfsg ~ beta1-2 is installed)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

How do I solve this dependency?

```
root @ server :/ # apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists ... ready
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... ready
You might want to run `apt-get-f install 'to correct them.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libgssapi-krb5-2: Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.10.1 + dfsg-4) but 1:10 + dfsg ~ beta1-2 is installed
E: unmet dependencies. Try using-f.
```

I have a server with Ubuntu 12:04 erp system and database.
I can not lose information.
If I follow the command suggested I lose my data.

```
root @ server :/ # apt-get install-f
Reading package lists ... Ready
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Ready
Correcting dependencies ... Ready
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  sound-theme-freedesktop-libplist1 libgconf 2-4 gconf2-common python-libcdio13 libtwolame0 pyorbit libgnome2-0 python-numpy python-avahi usbmuxd
  libcaca0 libsamplerate0 gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly libavc1394 libx264-120-0 libbonobo2-common libgpod-common gstreamer0.10-alsa libgnome2-bin
  libimobiledevice2 python-matplotlib-data git-man libbonobo2-0 python-egenix-mxtools libgnomevfs2-common python-mutagen libspeex1 gconf2
  libjack-jackd2-0 libavahi-glib1 xsane-common python-pyinotify liblapack3gf libgpod4 libcanberra0 libwavpack1 gnome2.4 libsoup-1-tdb-tools
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good libIDL ttf-lyx-common libgconf2-4 libiec61883 libmp3lame0-0 libgnome2-common python-daap libgnomevfs2-0 mlock alsa-utils
  libidl0 liba52-0.7.4 libvorbisfile3 libflac8 libraw1394-11 libshout3 libdv4 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer0.10-x libblas3gf python-gobject
  libusbmuxd1 libgnomeui-common libsidplay1 alsa-base python-liborbit2 libtag1c2a gst0.10 libmad0 libgfortran3 libopencore-amrnb0 gconf-service
  python-xlib libbonoboui2-common python-python-egenix-mxdatetime gpod amrwb0 libopencore-python-gconf linux-sound-base libmpeg2-4
  libgnomecanvas2-common gconf-backend-service libtag1-vanilla
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt-transport-https avahi-daemon bind9 bind9-host bind9utils cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-filters cups-cups-pk-helper ppdc curl dnsutils
  ghostscript-cups ghostscript gimp git gnome-icon-theme gs-cjk-resource heirloom-mailx humanity-icon-theme libbind9 libbonoboui2-80-0
  libc-client2007e libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsdriver1 libcupsfilters-dev libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2
  libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcupt2-0-DownloadMethod-curl libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libdns81 libgail18 libgimp2.0 libglade2-0 libgnomecanvas2-0
  libgnomeui-0 libgs9 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgtk-perl, libgssapi 3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin-libhippocanvas 1-0 libisccfg82 libnss-mdns
  libpq5 libwebkitgtk librsvg2-common-1.0-0 stripe lsb lsb-core lsb-cxx lsb-desktop lsb-graphics lsb-printing notification-daemon openssh-client
  openssh-server php5-imap policykit-1-gnome postgresql postgresql-9.1 postgresql-client-9.1 printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-pnm2ppa
  glade2 python-python-gnome2 python-gtk2 python-hippocanvas python-matplotlib python-psycopg2 python-webkit samba samba-common-bin smbclient sane
  swat ssh ubuntu-standard whoopsie xpp xsane
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 90 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
22 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 251 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Comment: As it said try `sudo apt=get -f install`